# Siri shortcuts stopped working after deleting Shortcuts App

Tags: siri, shortcuts-app

I was testing something out, but in one of my apps I can set a voice command for a shortcut. I manage the shortcut in that app and don't use the Shortcuts App. But after I deleted the Shortcuts App those shortcuts I created in app stopped working.

I can see click the add button but Siri just says she doesn't understand.

Do I need the Shortcuts app to be able to use in app shortcuts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need the Shortcuts app to use Siri Shortcuts.

In iOS 13, Siri Shortcuts were integrated with the Shortcuts app and every Siri Shortcut is a ‘normal’ shortcut too.

See https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/101 at exactly 1:00:00

Comment: Is there any official docs saying this? I don't disagree from my experience, but I couldn't find anything documented. Also my apps just break, they don't say Shortcuts App is required, which sucks.

Comment: @Michael Added a source. The lack of a proper error message is likely a bug, which perhaps should be reported to Apple.